# How can I control the scrolling of a webpage with onclicks and prevent users from scrolling on their own?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I would like some guidance / ideas for the following problem: How can someone lock the scrolling of a web page in order to present content to the user in a specific sequential way? For example, I would like a web page to have 3 sections, and with an onclick to scroll to a specific section id_1, then with another on click to scroll to section id_2 etc., but only with the onclicks to do that scrolling and prevent the user to scroll by himself with his mouse or with the scroll bars. Thanks!

Comment: because it is usability anti pattern

Comment: @Lashane: unfortunately these are the specs !

Comment: then do following: 1. read rules of this site 2. delete this question 3. try to do it 4. ask questions if any

Comment: @Lashane: not very helpful but thank you my friend

Comment: A follow up / complimentary question in stack overflow can be also found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440644/is-it-possible-to-prevent-users-page-up-page-down-up-and-down-arrow-keys-from

Answer (score 1):

If these are your specs you absolutely have to follow, which I highly recommend against anyway, you could just make each section stretch to fill the screen and make them fixed. Then provide a button to toggle in between the different sections.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do, but the user is able to move between different pages (not with the provided buttons) but with other ways as well like using the side bar (I know how to deactivate it) or using his mouse wheel (I do not know how to deactivate it) or with using even select all and then using the keys. So how can someone "lock" somehow this scrolling options and allow only scrolling through buttons?

Comment: I think I found an answer. Make every page responsive to any screen and use overflow: hidden in the body.