# Is it possible to prevent users Page Up, Page Down, Up and Down arrow keys from scroll functioning?

Tags: css, html, scroll

Using in html body

```css
overflow: hidden
```

I managed to control the scroll flow of a webpage. Is it possible to also prevent users Page Up, Page Down, Up and Down arrow keys from scroll functioning?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That is a bad practice and a bad design. Focus to make a good design instead of restricting the user's  choice. Coming to your question, yes it can be done with the help of javascript. Just disable the key events by using preventDefault or return false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will move to this direction. Can you please also point me to a link with some good reasons that establish this approach as a bad practice / design? Thank you again my friend...

Comment: I don't have links to establish that fact. But the default functionality should not be tampered if it is not being replaced with the better one. Although, if disabling the key is very critical to your design, then you can proceed with the answers below.

Comment: There are some target projects where you are required to limit user controls. It could be Apps, Video games, Specific frames in webpages. But for most situations like a traditional webpage this should be avoided. Some designs become a "bad" practice when the user is required to learn a custom UI when the situation could be resolved with an already friendly and known solution. Having in mind that you didn't specify the context where you require this, it's a completelly valid question.

Comment: Generally, hacking the browser's native UI is a double edged sword. On the one hand, it can produce nifty results; on the other, it could literally break the UI and hamper the average user's (or worse - the physically challenged user's) experience. It's true that in certain contexts breaking away from the native UI is desirable, but more than often it's just an exercise in visual vanity.

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution:

```
var ar = new Array(33, 34, 38, 40);

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: This did the job. I struggled for ages trying to do it on keyup (DOH!). In this case, I wanted to hack PgDn and PgUp to scroll EXACTLY 1 page. Most browsers scroll about 75% of a page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()`:

```
window.onkeydown=function(e){
   if(e.keycode==33 || e.keycode==34 || e.keycode==38 || e.keycode==40){
       e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

37 - left
38 - up
39 - right
40 - down

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   if(e.which>=36 && e.which<40){
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dgcj7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is part of a bookmarklet used for reading pages where I wanted PgDn or NumpadEnter to scroll down EXACTLY one page. The relevant part is:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  switch(e.code) {
  case 'PageDown':
  case 'NumpadEnter':
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight-10);
    break;

  case 'PageUp':
  case 'NumpadAdd':
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollBy(0, -(window.innerHeight-10));
    break;
  }
});
```